# Why getBoundsInLocal gets wrong coordinates?

Tags: java, javafx

The code is written in JavaFX.

I have a root panel, and a `VBox` on it. There are lots of little panels in the `VBox`.

I want to click on a button to add one little panel to the `VBox`, then pop up a message dialog on the new panel.

```
button.setOnAction(() -> {
    Node selectPanel = new Node();
    vbox.getChildren().add(selectPanel);
    Bounds bounds = selectPanel.localToScreen(selectPanel.getBoundsInLocal());
    showMessage(bounds);
});
```

But the message is not shown in the new panel's position.

I debug the code and find the bounds is the left top of the root panel (or vbox). could somebody tell me how to get the right coordinates of the new panel?

Comment: `Node` is abstract, so `Node selectPanel = new Node();` will not compile, so you must implement your own `Node` class. And the lambda expression is wrong too, as it has no arguments. Please post only code that compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not compiling (see my comment) but, the problem comes from the fact that even if `vbox.getChildren().add(selectPanel);` is called, the layout calculation will not (surely) happen.

You can force it by executing the following two statements after the mentioned line:

```
vbox.layout();
vbox.applyCss();
```

Comment: one more question. I find the coordinate is not precisely in the new panel's position. If I add 2 or more panel in the vbox in the same time, there is some offset in each message box. When I add many panels in the same time (for example more than 10) the message boxes will overlap. The bigger index the more offset.